# Interacting with mysql through sockets

Tags: mysql, sockets

I was wondering if there is a way to use mysql server through sockets.
What I want is connecting running queries and getting results by making socket connections and sending packets. Does anyone know how can I interact with mysql this way?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every language has a MySQL client, so I'm not sure why you want to do this.

But, you would basically have to reimplement the client library.  The protocol is by no means simple: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_ClientServer_Protocol.

You could perhaps write basic functionality, but once you get into all the features and corners of the protocol, it would be a project tremendous in scope (with no purpose).

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, I'm not planning to make a client for mysql, The goal is to understand the way a DBMS interacts with a client. I'm doing a little research on the way a DBMS works and I want to get more detailed information about any parts I can.

Comment: @AbcdEfg Ah.  I suppose it would be interesting to take a peak at the nitty gritty of how MySQL transmits data.  :)